# How to extract characters of a string between two characters in php?

Tags: php, string

I have an a string like this

```
$size = "facebook_page [600x315]";
```

I want to extract

`600x315`

I tried this

```
 preg_match('~[(.*?)]~', $size, $output);
 print_r($output[1]);
```

It doesn't give me any output.
Where am I going wrong? If there's another method it'd help a lot.

Comment: [`preg_match('~\[(.*?)]~', $size, $output);`](https://ideone.com/xLvT2S)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  thanks it worked